# The mouse events for my color picker are not working correctly. How can i make it so that my mouse position aligns with my color selector in canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am currently building a custom color picker. The issues i am running into are that the events for the mouse are causing my color picker to not behave as it should. I have a couple calculations for the position of the mouse within my canvas and also a color selector that should be aligning with the mouse when i click and move the mouse inside it. However, that is not happening and i can't figure out why.

I have tried calculating the bounding areas of the rectangle and getting the center position of the canvas so that i have something to base my mouse position out of. But when i click on the canvas the color selector does not align correctly to my mouse. Below is the JavaScript for my color picker. i will include the GitHub also for reference.

https://github.com/proamateurr/color-picker-project

and live preview:

https://proamateurr.github.io/color-picker-project/

```
class colorPickerClass {
    // Constructor to initialize the color picker
    constructor(target, width, height) {
        this.target = target;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.target.width = width;
        this.target.height = height;

        // Get the 2D rendering context of the canvas
        this.ctx = this.target.getContext("2d");

        // Initial position and dimensions of the color selector
        this.colorSelector = {x: 250, y: 250, width: 12, height: 0};

        //Event listeners for user interactions
        this.listenForEvents();
    }

    //Draw method to render the color picker
    draw() {
        this.build();
    }

    // Build method to create and render the gradients on the canvas
    build() {
        //Creating the gradient color stops
        const gradient = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
            this.width / 2, 0, 10,
            this.width / 2, 0, this.width * 1.17
          );
        
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(242, 13, 13, 0.8)');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(230, 26, 26, 0.6)');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(204, 51, 51, 0.4)');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(166, 89, 89, 0.2)');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
            
        const gradient2 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
            this.width * 0.8535533905932738, this.height * 0.14644660940672622, 10,
            this.width * 0.8535533905932738, this.height * 0.14644660940672622, this.width * 1.14
            );
            
        gradient2.addColorStop(0, '#ffbf00');
        gradient2.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(242, 185, 13, 0.8)');
        gradient2.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(230, 179, 26, 0.6)');
        gradient2.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(204, 166, 51, 0.4)');
        gradient2.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(166, 147, 89, 0.2)');
        gradient2.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
        
        const gradient3 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
            this.width, this.height / 2, 10,
            this.width, this.height / 2, this.width * 1.17
          );
        
        gradient3.addColorStop(0, '#80ff00');
        gradient3.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(128, 242, 13, 0.8)');
        gradient3.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(128, 230, 26, 0.6)');
        gradient3.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(128, 204, 51, 0.4)');
        gradient3.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(128, 166, 89, 0.2)');
        gradient3.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
        
        const gradient4 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
            this.width * 0.8535533905932738, this.height * 0.8535533905932738, 10,
            this.width * 0.8535533905932738, this.height * 0.8535533905932738, this.width * 1.14
            );
    
        gradient4.addColorStop(0, '#00ff40');
        gradient4.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(13, 242, 70, 0.8)');
        gradient4.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(26, 230, 77, 0.6)');
        gradient4.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(51, 204, 89, 0.4)');
        gradient4.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(89, 166, 108, 0.2)');
        gradient4.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
        
        const gradient5 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
            this.width * 0.50000000000001, this.height * 1, 10,
            this.width * 0.50000000000001, this.height * 1, this.width * 1.14
            );
        
        gradient5.addColorStop(0, '#0ff');
        gradient5.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(13, 242, 242, 0.8)');
        gradient5.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(26, 230, 230, 0.6)');
        gradient5.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(51, 204, 204, 0.4)');
        gradient5.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(89, 166, 166, 0.2)');
        gradient5.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
    
        const gradient6 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
            this.width * 0.1464466094067263, this.height * 0.8535533905932738, 10,
            this.width * 0.1464466094067263, this.height * 0.8535533905932738, this.width * 1.14
            );
        
        gradient6.addColorStop(0, '#0040ff');
        gradient6.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(13, 70, 242, 0.8)');
        gradient6.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(26, 77, 230, 0.6)');
        gradient6.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(51, 89, 204, 0.4)');
        gradient6.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(89, 108, 166, 0.2)');
        gradient6.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
        
        const gradient7 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
        0, this.height * 0.50000000000001, 10,
        0, this.height * 0.50000000000001, this.width * 1.17
        );
    
        gradient7.addColorStop(0, '#7f00ff');
        gradient7.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(128, 13, 242, 0.8)');
        gradient7.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(128, 26, 230, 0.6)');
        gradient7.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(128, 51, 204, 0.4)');
        gradient7.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(128, 89, 166, 0.2)');
        gradient7.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');
        
        const gradient8 = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(
        this.width * 0.146447, this.height * 0.146447, 10,
        this.width * 0.146447, this.height * 0.146447, this.width * 1.14
        );
        
        gradient8.addColorStop(0, '#ff00bf');
        gradient8.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(242, 13, 185, 0.8)');
        gradient8.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(230, 26, 179, 0.6)');
        gradient8.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(204, 51, 166, 0.4)');
        gradient8.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(166, 89, 147, 0.2)');
        gradient8.addColorStop(0.5, 'hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0)');

        //Apply the gradient to the canvas
        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient8;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient7;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient6;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient5;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient4;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient3;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient2;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        //Draw the color selector
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(this.colorSelector.x, this.colorSelector.y, this.colorSelector.width, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "white" 
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 8;
        this.ctx.shadowBlur = 4;
        this.ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(70, 70, 70)"
        this.ctx.stroke()
        this.ctx.closePath();

    }

    // Event listeners for mouse interactions
    listenForEvents() {
        let isMouseDown = false;

        const onMouseDown = (e) => {
        let rect = this.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        let currentX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        let currentY = e.clientY - rect.top;

        // Check if the mouse is within the circular canvas
        if (
            Math.pow(currentX - this.width / 2, 2) +
            Math.pow(currentY - this.height / 2, 2) <=
            Math.pow(this.width / 2, 2)
        ) {
            isMouseDown = true;
        } else {
            // Update the color selector position
            this.updateColorSelectorPosition(currentX, currentY);
        }
        };

        const onMouseMove = (e) => {
        let rect = this.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        let currentX = e.clientX - rect.left;
        let currentY = e.clientY - rect.top;

        // If the mouse is down, update the color selector position
            if (isMouseDown) {
                this.updateColorSelectorPosition(currentX, currentY);
            }
        };

        const onMouseUp = () => {
        isMouseDown = false;
        };

        // Add event listeners to the canvas
        this.target.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown);
        this.target.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
        // window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        //     this.width = this.target.width = window.innerWidth;
        //     this.height = this.target.height = window.innerHeight;
        //   });
    }

    // Function to update the color selector position
    updateColorSelectorPosition(x, y) {
        // Calculate the distance from the center of the canvas
        let distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(x - this.width / 2, 2) + Math.pow(y - this.height / 2, 2)
        );

        // Check if the mouse is still within the circular canvas
        if (distance <= this.width / 2) {
        // Update the color selector position
        this.colorSelector.x = x;
        this.colorSelector.y = y;
        } else {
        // If the mouse moves outside the circle, calculate the position on the circle
        let angle = Math.atan2(y - this.height / 2, x - this.width / 2);
        this.colorSelector.x =
            this.width / 2 + (this.width / 2 - 10) * Math.cos(angle);
        this.colorSelector.y =
            this.height / 2 + (this.height / 2 - 10) * Math.sin(angle);
        }
    }
}

//Create an instance of the color picker
const colorPicker = new colorPickerClass (document.getElementById("canvas"), 500, 500);

//Update the color picker continuously
setInterval(colorPicker.draw(), 1);
```

Comment: The issue here is that your rectangles don't match.  If you log the `rect` you get in the mouse events, you'll see that the rectangle is only 470x470.  If I multiply `currentX` and `currentY` by 500 / 470, then the points very nearly line up.